# I need to import a GIT repository into an existing RTC project?

Tags: git, rtc

I need to import a GIT repository into an existing RTC project. I've found a page that describes how to synchronize GIT with RTC, but that's not enough as the two projects are going to merge at the source level and I really want to migrate GIT history.

From what I've read so far this not possible today, but do you have any suggestion about an alternative migration plan or a good-enough solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, that kind of import is not an exhaustive one, but focuses on the main branches and tag of the Git repo.

For each branch, you create an RTC stream, and its associate repository workspace, and sandbox.

You can then simply checkout the relevant tags (from the oldest to the newest) directly in the sandbox (with a `.jazzignore` in order to ignore the `.git` repo folder).
RTC will detect automatically the changed, added or removed file, and will propose to make the relevant change set to be committed.